# ConnectionRefusedError when trying to host python socket server on raspberry pi

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a basic python networking program. All I'm trying to do is send strings of text back and forth between the server and the client. I'm trying to host the server on my Raspberry Pi, and connect with a client on Windows 10. The program works great locally on my computer, but when I try to connect to my server, it gives me `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.` My server code is as follows:

```
import socket               # Import socket module
import netifaces as ni

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.bind((host, port))

#host_ip = ni.ifaddresses('wlan0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']

host_ip = "bruh?"

print("Server started! \nHostname: " + host + " \nIP: " + host_ip + " \nPort: " + str(port))

s.listen()                  # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print('Got connection from', addr)
   output = "Welcome to the server!".encode()
   c.send(output)

   c.close()
```

Client code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

host = 192.168.1.21
port = 12345

s.connect((host, int(port)))

noResponse = False
serverResponse = s.recv(1024).decode()
    
print(serverResponse)
    
s.close()
```

Does anyone know what my problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a few reasons you are getting a ConnectionRefusedError, please try the following:

1. Check that no firewall is blocking your connection.
2. Double-check the server IP, if it is wrong you may get this error.
3. Try to use Hercules to check the connection.

Also, I would change the code as follow:

Server:

```
import socket

HOST = ''  # localhost
PORT =     # IMPORTANT !! Do not use reserved ports 

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    sock.listen()
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print('Data: ',data)
            conn.sendall('RT')
```

Client:

```
import socket

HOST = ''  # server IP address
PORT =     # server port

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall('Hello, I am the Client')
    data = sock.recv(1024)

print('Received', data)
```

By doing this you are using a TCP connection and you can test your code with different TCP server and client emulators.

Comment: 1. I can verify that there is no firewall blocking my connection, because I am able to ping both from the server to the client, and from the client to the server. 2. The server IP is correct. 3. I am trying to connect to a server that is on my LAN network. My program works fine if I try to run both the server and the client locally on my machine, but not when I offload the server to another device. Are you saying that I can’t  to connect one device to another on my local network?

Comment: Try changing the code to create a TCP socket (see the example about), then test the code using a TCP/IP Client Server terminal like Hercules doing so will help you to see where is the problem and establish the connection. @NinjaPixels